# Showing download progress as a notification in React Native+Expo on Android?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

Is there a way to show a download progress as a notification using expo-file-system API? I know I can create a component, which will render a progress bar depending on how much bytes are already downloaded, but I want a native progress bar, which usually pops up in notifications, when you are downloading something in a browser.

Although the question is specific to Android, any additional information associated with iOS is welcome.

Thank you!